# Return all rows with IDs that are not present in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a row entity, say `Book`, in table `Library`. I also have a table `Borrowings` with rows representing `Borrowing` entity.

`Book` has a primary key which is used in a `Borrowing` row to mark a book as borrowed in field `book_id`. There can be 0-n `Borrowing` rows that can be connected to a single `Book`.

- If there are no `Borrowing` rows for a specific book, then the `Book` is available.
- If there are 1-n `Borrowing` rows for a specific book with `return_date` less than current date, then the `Book` is available.
- There can be only 1 `Borrowing` row with `return_date` in the future. If this one is present, the `Book` is borrowed and not available for readers.

My question is - how do I find all books that are available for borrowing because they fulfill any of these criteria?

- Have no `Borrowing` rows with their ID referenced.
- Have no `Borrowing` rows with `return_date` in the future.

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What is `n` ? Are there more than one copies available for any particular title? Also: please add table definitions and sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query

```
SELECT *
FROM library l
LEFT JOIN borrowing b 
 ON l.book_id = b.book_id
WHERE (b.book_id IS NULL
     OR NOW()::date - b.return_date::date > 0)
```

Hope this should help you out.